# how can i cases while updating records?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I am using two update queries where in first update query i am setting nav order = 0 of a record then in another query I am decrementing nav order by 1 to have nav order in proper order, how can I the perform both of this operation with only one update query ? any help would be appreciated.

```
<cfif _q.is_nav_item EQ 1 AND arguments.is_nav_item EQ 0>
     <cfquery datasource="#getDSN()#">
        UPDATE content
        SET nav_order = 0
        WHERE id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
        AND site__id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.site__id#" />
        ;   
        UPDATE content
        SET nav_order = nav_order - 1
            WHERE nav_order > <cfqueryparam value="#_q.nav_order#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_tinyint" />
        AND site__id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.site__id#" />
                    ;
        </cfquery>              
    </cfif>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use one update query to do both?  Your current code works and it's quite readable.  Just use transaction.

Comment: @Henry - absolutely it works fine..... but my TL want it to be done in one query...I don't know what makes him to think about it.

Comment: If you are going to make a change like that, there should be a *good* reason. It seems unlikely to yield any performance benefit, and more importantly, the query will be harder to understand. So what is the perceived benefit here?

Comment: Your TL?? Tender Lover?  Tiny Llama?  Terrible Lawyer?

Comment: @DanBracuk Team Lead? I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a case construct which I think is just as readable as two queries

```
<cfquery datasource="#getDSN()#">
UPDATE content
SET nav_order = case 
when id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" /> then 0
when nav_order > <cfqueryparam value="#_q.nav_order#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_tinyint" /> 
then nav_order - 1
else nav_order 
end

WHERE site__id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.site__id#" />
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<cfif _q.is_nav_item EQ 1 AND arguments.is_nav_item EQ 0>
     <cfquery datasource="#getDSN()#">
        UPDATE content
        SET nav_order = IF(id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />, 0, IF(nav_order > <cfqueryparam value="#_q.nav_order#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_tinyint" />, nav_order - 1, nav_order))
        WHERE site__id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.site__id#" />
    </cfquery>          
</cfif>
```

For the record, I agree with @Henry that the two existing, separate queries are preferable.